# Why did a moderator delete a highly voted answer and nobody answered the flag I raised?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, spam, specific-answer, custom-flags

Recently a moderator deleted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59056440/5623035) with 37 upvotes and it said:

> This answer was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown - you can see the revision history for details.

I should mention that recently I added a new section to the answer containing a link to my repository with some sort of *walls of code*. I thought that the deletion could have been because of this section and I removed it.

I flagged for undeletion and asked if this was the source of the issue. But I don't think preventing from being a *wall of code* is *spam or rude or abusive*.

Although it's obviously not *spam or rude or abusive* and upvotes have confirmed that, I raised a flag and asked the moderators about it almost at the time of the act, but it's been two days and I haven't got a response.

Why do you think was the reason for the deletion?

Is there a way to bring it back to life?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The root problem here is you edited something [promotional](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) into your post (I think yivi covered that fairly well). It was flagged as spam and later deleted by a moderator. It wasn't deleted via flag so you didn't get a -100 penalty. The spam/rude notice is because the flag was marked helpful by the delete.

I see you've edited that block out but your response here is... interesting

> I flagged for undeletion and asked if this was the source of the issue. But I don't think preventing from being a wall of code is spam or rude or abusive.

That's not quite how your flag reads

> Why is this post deleted? it contains very useful content for SO members and been here for a long time. The recently added section also is a completely open-source and it's not a link only or wall of code answer. That section just removed if it violates the SO's rules.

It's a custom flag, which is slow, but we get lots of flags angry or combative about deletion. You also don't make it clear that you get why it was deleted until the end. Since this Meta has cleared that up it's undeleted. But if your flag had read something like

> I added a link to a project I wrote and apparently that got my post deleted. I have removed that block. Can it be undeleted please?

it might have been handled sooner since it acknowledged the problem up front and avoided sounding combative

Comment: Oh. Thanks for your clear, straight forward answer. That's why I voted you in the last election. I will try to make my questions and flags to be more clear next time.

Comment: There are other answers under that question that have similarly annoying animated GIFs. I think they should all be treated equally. If animation must be removed, then all should be removed. Now, this particular post is talking about activity indicators, so from one perspective it makes sense to have animation, on the other hand it makes harder to focus on actual answers.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar The problem there was the link. As long as the images are related to the answer, it isn't a problem. And the question is indeed related to animations so some animation is to be expected. Also, this particular image wasn't one animation, it was nine, so I can see why it would be annoying.

Comment: @Machavity _"The problem there was the link"_ Why though? Can you please elaborate? The link was to a library that the OP disclosed that they maintain and AFAICT, it's related to the question/answer. Putting aside whether or not the image was annoying (which is subjective), did that part of the answer break any rules?

Comment: @41686d6564 I can't speak to why this mod felt it was worthy of deletion, but self-promotion is [something SO generally discourages](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), even with disclosure. As I've told other SE mods, disclosure is merely a fig leaf. Add in that the problematic content was at the top (where it was highly visible in the mod tool) and it's probable they saw the self-promotion and simply deleted. Mods in general deal with that one all the time, and when we err, we tend to err on the side of deletion there.

Comment: @Machavity Why not edit the spammy part out? I've seen you do it once, why not for this post? The only time spam shouldn't be edited is if the entire answer is spam, which in this case it is not, right?

Comment: @10Rep Because the mod console is sometimes clunky in that regard. It tends to show the top of the post and not much other context. It's an easy mistake to make here. Mods are human.

Comment: So if someone else linked his library it was ok, but he can't link his library himself?

Comment: @Honey We do allow some linking of useful content (i.e. a library that can help answer the question) but we do require disclosure and that you avoid making it overly promotional. Keep in mind any user linking to the same thing repeatedly is subject to having their posts deleted, regardless of whether or not it's their content.

Answer (score 21):

First, regarding the flag: custom flags can take a long time to be processed. Be patient.

I'm pretty sure the problem was the way you presented the link to your library on [revision 13](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59056440/13).

There is a huge animated banner that links to the library repo. You disclose you are the author by saying "I have implemented", but even then the link serves only to promote the library, there is no useful information in the post.

(There is no useful information in the post in regards to the linked library; there **is** useful information if one goes beyond that, and up to revision 12 the post seemed fine).

> [image: screenshot of revision 13 of deleted answer, showing a big animated banner with multiple widgets spinning or pulsating]

For those that can't see the post, all those red widgets are either spinning or pulsating, and the whole thing is a link to the mentioned library. I'm including only the problematic part of the answer, which is almost 2100 chars long. The rest of the post is detailed and looks fine to my non-expert eyes.

That there is a link without useful content, and the spammy tactic of inserting a big animated banner, are not good things to do.

If you want to link your library, that's fine. Just add the link (and as you did, disclose authorship) with a couple of examples of **how to use it.**. That way, the answer and the link remain useful for future visitors without having to go to an external site. And please, remove the animated banner. Add images only in ways that fit organically in the post to add information, not for promotion.

Responding to some comments:

> [regarding the animated ad] I'm not a fan too, but I should make the answer stand out in other answers.

No, you should not. Just focus on the content, not on standing out from the other posts.

> And the moderator was very expert in the JS field I think. Maybe he/she doesn't get the relation at the first sight.

One doesn't need to be an expert on Swift to see the problem here.

> that's the reason I've deleted that section immediately. I didn't like that either.

You removed **after** the post had been deleted. In reaction to a mod deleting the post as spam. It's fine that you removed it, but the mod had no way to know that you were going to do that in the future.

> But the point is that can be commented instead of getting aggressive deletion I think.

Deletion is not aggressive. Being spammy is a hard "no" on the site. Deletion for breaking the self-promotion rules is warranted.

Now that you removed that part, you just need to wait on a mod to see your custom flag, and hopefully they'll undelete the post.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. I think you should include other parts of the answer in that image so people don't think it's just that bad.

Comment: It's too long the include the whole thing, I've just included an edit mentioning that rest of the answer was fine, and that up to revision 12  the post seemed OK. I hope you find it an acceptable compromise. I'm sure you didn't act in bad faith, so it's all good. The post will very likely be undeleted in the future.

Comment: if the edit only removed spammy animation then remainder still looks troublesome ([meta-tag:link-only-answers])

Comment: @gnat The answer includes much more (not included in my screenshot). It's 2100 characters long. So it would never qualify as a link-only answer. But even if removing the animation, I would advise that the link be accompanied with supporting material in the post, of course.

Comment: Maybe it's just me (and I'm not an expert in Swift) but I see nothing wrong with that part of the answer (except that it might've been better at the _end_ of the answer). Why? Because it's completely relevant to the post where the author explains how to do animations. The answer was pretty detailed, so I view this as just an added bonus. What about the animated image? IMO, still relevant. It shows examples of the animations the library supports. Other answers in the same question also included animated images: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59171234), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59471528)

Comment: Here's a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/FPUXuoK.png) of the remaining part of the answer (if the OP doesn't mind) for users <10K.